# Don't work interractive widgets

Tags: python, callback, widget, bokeh

CustomJS.from_py_func(callback) does not work well.
I can display graph and widget, but I cann't handle callback function well.

## ---sample code

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button

reset_output()
#output_file("button.html",mode="inline")
output_notebook(resources=INLINE)

x = [x for x in range(0, 10)]
y = x

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

def line_visible(arg):
    if arg == 1: ll.visible = True
    else: ll.visible = False

plot = Figure(plot_width=200, plot_height=200)
ll = plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)
line_visible(1) # visible = True: work well! line_visible(0) is OK, too.

def callback(source=source, window=None):
    data = source.data
    act = cb_obj.get('active') # 0:CHG,1:DSP,2:NOT
    if 0 in act: # CHG work well
        x, y = data['x'], data['y']
        for i in range(len(x)):
            x[i] = x[i]*1.1
            y[i] = y[i]*2.0
    if 1 in act: line_visible(1) # DSP: ?
    if 2 in act: line_visible(0) # NOT:visible=False: don't work.
    source.change.emit()

toggle1 = CheckboxButtonGroup(labels=["CHG","DSP","NOT"],
    active=[], # all are not active: if active=[0,1,2], all are active
    callback=CustomJS.from_py_func(callback)) #<= need Flexx(0.4.1)

layout = column(toggle1,plot)
show(layout)
```

## ---end of code---

I got a new versions.
conda update anaconda
conda update --all
but don't work well

Comment: You're going to need to explain your problem in far greater detail than "not work well."

Comment: This problem is not to work the visible attribution in callback function. 
The visible attribution can work well outside of callback function.
I thought this is bug of "CustomJS.from_py_func()".

Comment: line_visible() is fine. When I use widget, callback() can work. CHG button can cahnge the data. But NOT button can change the visible attribution.

Answer (score 1):

`CustomJS.from_py_func()` takes a function that you have written as python code and transpiles it, as [PyScript](http://flexx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyscript/), to JavaScript. This is an interesting feature because it can allow you to write Python-like-code that can run in the browser. However, the code that `from_py_func()` generate **is not Python** and does not have access to the Python runtime environment. This means that your `callback` function does not have access to `line_visible` or `ll` because these are defined in the python runtime, not in the browser which is where the plot is rendered and your callback function runs.

`CustomJS()` callbacks allow you to pass variables from the python environment into your JavaScript code through the `args` variable, <s>but there doesn't seem to be a similar functionality provided in `from_py_func()`</s>. This can be achieved is a `from_py_func()` callback by passing variables directly to the callback function as default arguments such as `source=source`. It is important to note that this will only work for Bokeh objects and not regular Python objects. Below is an updated version of `callback` that I was able to get working:

```
def callback(source=source, ll=ll, window=None):
    def line_visible(arg):
        if arg == 1: ll.visible = True
        else: ll.visible = False

    data = source.data
    act = cb_obj.get('active') 
    if 0 in act: 
        x, y = data['x'], data['y']
        for i in range(len(x)):
            x[i] = x[i]*1.1
            y[i] = y[i]*2.0
    if 1 in act: line_visible(1)
    if 2 in act: line_visible(0) 
    source.change.emit()
```

Comment: Thank you for careful advice.

Comment: Thank you for careful advice. I was solved by watching the sample of the following sites. https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#visible-property

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't know that args could be passed in through a separate method. After taking a closer look at the docs on `CustomJS` and looking through some of the source code, I realized that it is possible to pass Bokeh objects directly to a `from_py_func()` callback. I updated my aswer with a solution that should work with `from_py_func()`.